# Python 3 Reciving email problems

Tags: python, email, imap

I'm writing a script to receive emails from my gmail email in python. I'm managing to download the raw email however I am then unable to access certain types of it, E.G BODY, TO, FROM etc.

```
import imaplib, email
msrvr = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
unm = 'stackoverflow@gmail.com'
pwd = 'lovetocode'
msrvr.login(unm,pwd)
stat,cnt = msrvr.select('Inbox')
stat, dta = msrvr.fetch(cnt[0], '(RFC822)')
b = email.message_from_string(str(dta))
print(b)
print(b['[To]'])
msrvr.close()
msrvr.logout()
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You didn't parse the email :). See `email` module for parsing MIME.

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier to use native Python Google SDK's for working with their email:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/

The `imaplib` module you are using is will only give you a subset of all gmail features..

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that parses an email and prints some header fields:

```
msg = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
for field in ('From', 'Subject', 'Received', 'Message-ID'):
    print '{0}: {1}'.format(field, msg[field])
```

For debugging, also print the raw parts of the `Message` object:

```
print msg.__dict__
```

(Note: I'm using Python2.7, but I believe there's not much difference.)